# Recursive function issue in PHP

Tags: php, function, recursion

I put the below function inside a class

I try to call it again inside this function (I have made a recursive call inside this function `$this->buildMenu($this->itemId, $menuData);`)

only without the recursive call this function works, else it does not return any value.

```
// menu builder function, parent_id 0 is the root 
function buildMenu($parent_id, $menuData)
{       
    $this->html = ''; 
    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parent_id])) 
    { 
        if($parent_id=='0') $this->html = '<ul class="menu responsive-menu sf-js-enabled">';
        else $this->html = '<ul>';
        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parent_id] as $this->itemId) 
        { 
            if($this->itemId=='1'){$this->html .= '<li><a href="'.PATH.'">' . $menuData['items'][$this->itemId]['menu_name'].'</a>';}
            else $this->html .= '<li class=""><a href="?action='. md5($menuData['items'][$this->itemId]['menu_link']).'">' . $menuData['items'][$this->itemId]['menu_name'].'</a>';
            $this->html .= $this->buildMenu($this->itemId, $menuData); 
            $this->html .= '</li>'; 
        } 
        $this->html .= '</ul>'; 
    } 

    return $this->html;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the value of `$this->itemId` is being changed at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with `$this->html = '';`.
It seems like `$html` is a class variable, so each recursive call to the function, you initialize it to be an empty string.
Try using it as a local function variable.

Answer (score 0):

First off, replace `$this->html` with `$html`: you're throttling the value of it with an empty string when your recurse, which isn't what you're intending, I'm guessing.

Comment: thanks very much pal, you are absolutely right. it works perfectly as I expected it to be.